# java web Restful no funciona

Tags: java, webservice, jsp, restful

Cuando en el cliente `java web` ingreso el número y hago clic en calcular el factorial aparece

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Internal Server Error
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found

este es el **index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Calcular factorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <form action="calcular.do" style="font-family:arial">
    Numero :<br>
    <input type="text" name="base" style="text-align:right"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="calcular" name="Calcular" />
    <br><br>
    Resultado:<br>
    <input type="text" name="resultado" value="${result}"
           style="text-align:right"/><br><br>
    </form>
 </div>           
 </body>
 </html>
```

este es el servlet Calcular.java

```
 package controlador;

 import Webservicce.ClientRest;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
*
* @author x2010s
*/
@WebServlet(name = "Calcular", urlPatterns = {"/calcular.do"})
public class Calcular extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and   <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ClientRest rest = new ClientRest();
    String base = request.getParameter("base");
    String factorial = rest.factorial(base);
    request.setAttribute("factorial",factorial);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

 }

 // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

En el servlet, el método factorial debe llamarse desde el restful, para calcular el factorial con el número ingresado

Este es el **RESTful** Java Client importado

```
package Webservicce;

import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

public class ClientRest {

private WebTarget webTarget;
private Client client;
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/SimpleRESTweb/webresources";

public ClientRest() {
    client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("factorial");
}

public String factorial(String base) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    if (base != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("base", base);
    }
    return resource.request().get(String.class);
}

public void close() {
    client.close();
}

}
```

El error aparece en el cliente java web. No entiendo porque no calcula el factorial el **restful**

este es el log de glassfish

[2018-04-19T22:54:46.129-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=183 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1524196486129] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Calcular]: Servlet.service() for servlet Calcular threw exception
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1008)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at Webservicce.ClientRest.factorial(ClientRest.java:41)
    at controlador.Calcular.processRequest(Calcular.java:37)
    at controlador.Calcular.doGet(Calcular.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:34.500-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00092] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=223 _ThreadName=Thread-35] [timeMillis: 1524198214500] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server shutdown initiated]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:34.613-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00028] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=223 _ThreadName=Thread-35] [timeMillis: 1524198214613] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@1f387978 from service registry.]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:34.615-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=223 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1524198214615] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FileMonitoring shutdown]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:34.626-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00002] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=223 _ThreadName=Thread-35] [timeMillis: 1524198214626] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:34.627-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00001] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=223 _ThreadName=Thread-35] [timeMillis: 1524198214627] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.167-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.default] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215167] [levelValue: 900] [[

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.(SessionManager.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.removeSessionFromGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.undeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2982)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.close(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.closeEMFs(JPADeployer.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:405)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.disable(ApplicationLifecycle.java:2128)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.disable(ApplicationLifecycle.java:113)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.stopApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.preDestroy(ApplicationLoaderService.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.preDestroyMe(ClazzCreator.java:339)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.dispose(ClazzCreator.java:404)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.dispose(SystemDescriptor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.destroyOne(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:328)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.destroyOne(RunLevelContext.java:101)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.destroy(ServiceHandleImpl.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$DownQueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1270)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.177-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215177] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher']]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.177-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215177] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Apr 19 22:52:19 COT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.181-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215181] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.181-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215181] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 19 22:52:18 COT 2018]; root of context hierarchy]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.198-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215198] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The web application [/Taller_Spring_7] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.398-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00092] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=231 _ThreadName=Thread-42] [timeMillis: 1524198215398] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server shutdown initiated]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.399-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00029] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=231 _ThreadName=Thread-42] [timeMillis: 1524198215399] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Exception while unregistering: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service already unregistered.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:123)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.unregisterService(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.java:93)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.stop(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopServer.doExecute(StopServer.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopDomainCommand.execute(StopDomainCommand.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at org.glassfish.api.AsyncImpl$1$1.run(AsyncImpl.java:76)
]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.946-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215946] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher']]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.947-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215947] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Apr 19 22:52:45 COT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.975-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215975] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:35.975-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [tid: _ThreadID=229 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1524198214661] [timeMillis: 1524198215975] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 19 22:52:44 COT 2018]; root of context hierarchy]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:36.797-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=232 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1524198216797] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource]]]

[2018-04-19T23:23:36.816-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [ra.stop-successful] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=234 _ThreadName=Thread-45] [timeMillis: 1524198216816] [levelValue: 800] [[
  RAR7094: __ds_jdbc_ra shutdown successful.]]

Comment: Agrega la traza completa del error.

Comment: ya  agregue la traza completa del error

Comment: Por algún motivo tu aplicación no está encontrando el recurso bajo la URL http://localhost:8080/SimpleRESTweb/webresources/factorial por lo que obtienes un código de error HTTP 404 cuando intentas consumir el recurso. Prueba con esta URL sobre el navegador a ver que ocurre.